# loop over levels of a factor variable in a function

Tags: r, lapply

I have a dataframe, dat, with a covariate site coded as a factor with 31 different levels.

```
cas_1_sitea_586754968 0 0 1 2 0 sitea 
con_65_sitea_568859302 1 0 2 1 1 siteb
cas_9_siteb_0799700 0 0 0 0 0 siteb 
con_siteb_THR84569 2 0 0 1 0 sitea
```

I have a function that works when I apply it to one site variable at a time:

```
get_maf <- function(data){
    allele.count <- apply(data[,1:(ncol(data)-2)],2,sum)
    maf <- allele.count/(2*nrow(data))
    out <- paste((unique(data$site)),"_jp.maf",sep="")
    write.table(maf, out, col.names=F, quote=F)
}
```

But, when I try to loop over the data within each of the 31 sites using lapply like this:

```
lapply(unique(dat$site), get_maf, data = dat)
```

I get an error: `lapply(unique(jp$site), get_maf_jp, data = jp)
Error in FUN(c("aber", "ajsz", "asrb", "buls", "cati", "caws", "cims",  : 
  unused argument (c("aber", "ajsz", "asrb", "buls", "cati", "caws", "cims", "clo3", "cou3", "denm", "dubl", "edin", "egcu", "ersw", "gras", "irwt", "lie2", "lie5", "mgs2", "msaf", "munc", "pewb", "pews", "s234", "swe1", "swe5", "swe6", "top8", "ucla", "umeb", "umes")[[1]])`

Any insights into what I am doing wrong here are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `lapply(unique(dat$site), get_maf, data = dat)` expression is that it tries to pass two arguments to `get_maf`: first comes from `lapply`, and the second comes from `data=dat`. You can fix it like that: `lapply(unique(dat$site), function(s) {get_maf(data=dat[dat$site==s,]})`.

Alternatively, you can use

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(site) %>% get_maf
```

PS: if you're dealing with large data sets, consider using `allele.count <- colSums(data[,1:(ncol(data)-2)])` in the `get_maf` function instead of much slower `allele.count <- apply(data[,1:(ncol(data)-2)],2,sum)` that you have now.